# Matlab Event Finder is occasionally missing events

Tags: matlab

I've been working on a numerical model that has been giving me some trouble lately. I'm attempting to solve a time series for a system where there is an impact at a certain location. Obviously Matlab's event finder is for exactly this sort of situation, but it's failing me, in that it occasionally crosses the event threshold without triggering.

My system is a pendulum with a wall at -30 degrees. Should be pretty simple; solve until pendulum hits -30, stop, reverse velocity, etc. However, as you can see in my picture, it occasionally just swings right past -30 and doesn't stop integrating. The code is mostly a copy-paste job of the ball bounce example with the differential equation changed, but somehow it's not working properly. A photo of the problematic time series is here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws1cg.jpg]

and my code is here: https://gist.github.com/f892a764ca10027a3b89

```
function matlab_timeser
    k1 = .557;
    tstart = 0;
    tfinal = 1200;
    refine = 100;
    y0 = [-3.0*pi/180.0; 6.0*pi/180.0];

    options = odeset('Events',@events,'Refine',refine);

    tout = tstart;
    yout = y0.';                % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    teout = [];
    yeout = [];
    ieout = [];
    while max(tout) < tfinal
        [t,y,te,ye,ie] = ode113(@f,[tstart tfinal],y0,options);
        % Accumulate output.  
        nt = length(t);
        tout = [tout; t(2:nt)];
        yout = [yout; y(2:nt,:)];
        teout = [teout; te];    % Events at tstart are never reported.
        yeout = [yeout; ye];
        ieout = [ieout; ie];

        % Set the new initial conditions, with k attenuation.
        y0(1) = -30 * pi/180;
        y0(2) = -k1*y(nt,2);

        % A good guess of a valid first time step is the length of 
        % the last valid time step, so use it for faster computation.
        options = odeset(options,'InitialStep',t(nt)-t(nt-refine),'MaxStep',t(nt)-t(1));
        tstart = t(nt);
        %     plot(tout,yout(:,1)*180/pi)
        %     hold on
        %     plot([0 t(nt)],[-30 -30],'r')
        %     hold off
        %     pause()
    end

    plot(tout,yout(:,1)*180/pi)
    hold on
    plot([0 t(nt)],[-30 -30],'r')

end

function dydt = f(t, y)
    wf = 0.8008 * 2 * pi;
    param = [6e-4 6.087 2.1e-3 0.236 0.557];
    coul1 = param(1);
    w1 = param(2);
    z1 = param(3);
    AL =  param(4);
    dydt = [y(2); AL*(wf)^2*sin(wf*t)*cos(y(1))-(w1)^2*sin(y(1))-2.0*z1*w1*y(2)-coul1*((y(2)^2)+(w1)^2*cos(y(1)))*sign(y(2))];
end

function [value,isterminal,direction] = events(t,y)
    value = y(1) + 30*pi/180;     % Detect height = -30
    isterminal = 1;   % Stop the integration
    direction = 0;   % any direction

end
```

I've tried a few different ode solvers and while they give slightly different results, they all seem to miss events here and there.

If anyone has any insights into why Event may occasionally fail to notice an event, I'd appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: The link to your code doesn't appear to be working

Comment: Unfortunately I have no insights into this but my general advice would be to make the program and system simpler and simpler until Matlab stops failing and then maybe one can see something. If then the feeling is that Matlab should catch these events then Matlab support might also be a place to get answers.

Comment: The link works (2014-09-05) however, row 11 seems to contain a bug